Preventing high temps when running CPU at near max frequency for long periods of time during deep learning workloads
I recently built a rig with a Noctua DH15 and Intel i7-14700KF. I have the default case fans that came with my case (MUSETEX PC Case ATX). The temperature is pretty cool when playing games and never really goes beyond 80C (probably because the GPU is doing most of the work). Here's my full parts list for reference.
I also run deep learning experiments that also have some CPU-heavy tasks. These result in the CPU running at ~5.10 GHz for up to 6 hours or more (I think the max speed w/ overclock is 5.60 GHz). I think this is mostly due to the constant cycling of data from disk -> RAM -> GPU memory -> back to RAM.
I monitored the hardware while my code ran, here is the timeline of temperatures:

Hours 0-2: CPU core temperature creeps up to 90 C
Hours 2-onwards: CPU core temp fluctuates between 90-95 C

I wonder if this is "expected" behaviour for long usage times like this?
If not, is it due to some improper thermal paste/fan installation or maybe I just don't have strong enough cooling for intense tasks like these?
Update: HWInfo snapshot
Core ViD is the average voltage requested by each core, so each core is roughly requesting 1.418 V. The wattage being supplied is around 100W at peak. PL1 and PL2 are also shown.
Link to motherboard:

MSI B760 Gaming Plus WiFi Gaming Motherboard

Go to page 15 of the motherboard user guide ODF for a full list of specs:



"I wonder if this is "expected" behavior for long usage times like this?" - It is and it isn't. Your processor is design to run at various freqencies between it's base frequency and it's max boost frequency.  It was designed to do this 24/7. However, Intel 13th and 14th Intel processors have a bug in their microcode and the processor requests in most cases a higher voltage then it actually needs.

(cont)  OEM motherboards without question, provide this voltage to the CPU, the result is your processor runs hotter then it should.  Intel plans to release an updated microcode in August. When your OEM motherboard brand releases the firmware update to your motherboard will be after the date. Till that update is release other than manually under-volting your processor that really isn't much you can do.

(cont) I encourage you to research this topic to see if there is a better solution other than under-volting the processor until that update is released. What voltage is your processor requesting at the highest frequencies? There is no easy answer to this question, and you have not provided enough information, to explain the microcode problem in a full detailed answer. I wouldn't submit an answer until that microcode was released. The website you linked to does not work for me. So I have no idea what motherboard you have.

According to Intel, anything under 100°C is good and just fine even for extended periods of time. As Ramhound already stated, Intel seems to have pushed the envelope a bit too far in an attempt to stay competitive with AMD and let unrestricted power profiles get way too agressive. You can chose to limit your CPU's max power usage in the BIOS/UEFI to help remedy this.

N.B. 13th & 14th gen Intel chips have a defect, and overclocking is likely to cause permanent damage: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/intel-instability-unanswered-questions/, https://www.xda-developers.com/intel-selling-defective-13th-and-14th-gen-cpus/ , https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-confirms-manufacturing-defects-caused-instability-on-some-13th-gen-Raptor-Lake-processors.866772.0.html,

@Silbee - Intel 13th and 14th generation processors were NOT designed to run at a constant 100°C and if your processor is running at 100°C then it is will eventually degrade.  I know the junction temperature of the effected processors and is well below 100°C If it was as easy as setting a maximum voltage then Intel would have pushed an update 18 months ago.  That isn't how these power profiles on intel systems work.

@Ramhound https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/236783/intel-core-i7-processor-14700k-33m-cache-up-to-5-60-ghz.html  clearly states Tjunc 100°C. Secondly, setting the power limit to PL1 will result in a 125W TDP (if the bios implements the intel baseline profile correctly) and will most definitely result in significantly lower temperatures. None of this has anything to do with upcoming microcode update but everything to do with the existing Intel Baseline Profile power limit profiles. He asked if temps are normal, they are, and using PL1 will lower temps.

@Silbee—That is the entire point. The BIOS is providing exactly what the processor is requesting, which is too high of a voltage.

Thanks for the comments @Ramhound. I've added information about voltage and wattage being supplied while my code is running. I've also included some links that describe the motherboard. Not sure if high power is the issue, as I'm not hitting the PL1 of 250W

PL1 is supposed to be 125W, so its fair to assume your MB hasnt implemented things correctly. The only way to prevent this is by manually setting values. However like you show, things are hovering around 100W in which case you'd likely see lower temps. You could double check if the cooler makes good contact (fastened well, right amount of paste, ...). While intel's 14th gen CPUs seem to suffer from power problems, i still maintain that under 100°C should be fine even for extended usage. You could err on the side of caution and wait for the microcode update before running CPU intensive tasks.

@Silbee - Motherboard implemented it just fine the problem is the bloody processor is asking for to much voltage and the motherboard is just supplying it without any reservation.

While temperatures like this are generally normal, the question is about preventing it.
If you want to reduce the temperature the first step would be to install water cooling solution.  Start with a 240/280mm radiator/fan solution and if that isn't enough 360/380mm solution also exist.
A water cooling solution generally run between 110 and $150, but more expensive solutions exist.
More extreme solutions exist that basically involve hooking the CPU block to a refrigerator type system to drop the temperatures even further.  However, for 90% of people is not necessary and very expensive.
